# Some sort of MySQL connection error but the table updates just fine?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

It's late - there's something probably really simple that I'm missing, but I just can't figure it out right now.

My function:

```
    function likes()
{
    global $connection;

    $stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO likes (article_id, ip_address) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("is", $_GET['id'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if($result)
    {
        header("location:javascript://history.go(-1)");
    }
    else
    {
        exit('Something weird happened');
    }
    $stmt-close();
}
```

The function is being called in likePost.php (../../likes/ after http rewrite) with the following link:

```
<a href='../../likes/" . $post->id . "'><img src='/images/like.png' title='Like this post' alt='Like button' height='32' width='32'></a>
```

The only thing in likePost.php is

```
session_start();
include "../db.php";
include "functions.php";

likes();

include "includes/header.php";
```

In my mind, it SHOULD be working. But when I click the link, I always get a blank page with the words "Something weird happened". But the db was updated no problems.

Can anyone see what I can't seem to?

Comment: If you look at the `get_result()` page it states *Returns a resultset for successful SELECT queries, or FALSE for other DML queries or on failure*.  As you are doing this from an INSERT it will be false.

Comment: @NigelRen - but i use basically the exact same code for the posts, with no problems at all... and I just found out it was header("location:javascript://history.go(-1)"); creating the problem. I changed it to ("Location: /"); and there's no more problems. So... I just need to figure out how to go back to the previous page instead of root...

Comment: You can't mix PHP and JavaScript. This won't work. If you want PHP to redirect to another page you need to know the address. Also as Nigel pointed out the function will return false always. That `if` statement is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out it was `header("location:javascript://history.go(-1)");` creating the problem. I changed it to `("Location: /");` and there's no more problems. So... I just need to figure out how to go back to the previous page instead of root...